# Prove set contains its sup by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. By the intermediate-value theorem, the set $S=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)=0\}$ is nonempty. If $c=\sup S$, prove that $c\in S$.

This can be proven in many ways as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447260/intermediate-value-theorem-and-supremum/1447268?noredirect=1#comment2948035_1447268).

However none of those solutions show that $f(c)\ne 0$ leads to a contradiction.

How can I do so?

Comment: Why do you want to have a proof by contradiction when you can have a direct proof? Why not a proof by contradiction for $1+1=2$?

Comment: The professor suggested on doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $c \in [a, b]$ because $[a, b]$ is closed.

I'll use the word "ball" to mean "open set in the subspace topology" - that is, an open interval but where we chop off anything which lies outside $[a, b]$. $(\frac{a+b}{2}, b)$ is a ball, as is $(\frac{a+b}{2}, b]$, but $[\frac{a+b}{2}, b)$ is not. A "ball around $x$" is a ball which contains $x$.

Suppose $f(c) \not = 0$. If $f(c) > 0$ then by continuity we may find a ball $B$ around $c$ such that $f(c) > 0$ on that ball; but $c$ is a sup, so for all balls around $c$ there is a member of $S$ in that ball, so there is a member $s$ of $S$ in $B$. This is a contradiction because $f(s) = 0$ (since $s \in S$) and also $f(s) > 0$ (since $s \in B$). The proof is almost identical for $f(c) < 0$.

Comment: by ball you are referring to intervals correct?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit that in.

Comment: No worries, thank you

Comment: is there a way of looking at this without topology?

Comment: You may ignore the phrase about the subspace topology if you wish. Then the answer doesn't use the word "topology". However, you're talking about general properties of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ - there's very likely to be a topological interpretation to such a question, so it's hard to excise all the topological notions from such an answer.

Comment: Ok, I am still trying to make sense of the intervals proving this, thank you

Comment: A "ball" here is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$, but where if the interval escapes leftwards of $a$ and/or rightwards of $b$, we chop it off at $a$ and/or $b$. It's just a piece of bookkeeping so that we can be sure that our function is defined everywhere we're talking about.